# Android of things - Raspberry Pi BLE Advertising

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-things

So I'm trying to use a raspberry pi 3b running android of things to broadcast an advertisement over BLE. However I have a few issues:

```
mBluetoothAdapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported(); //returns a false boolean (meaning it doesn't support advertisements)

//however this is not null?
mBluetoothLeAdvertiser = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
```

I can start the advertisement and my AdvertiseCallback onStartSuccess listener is passing however I cannot see the pi?

I would expect android of things to be able to advertise or at least act as a beacon. Does anyone have a workaround or know of an alternative library? It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at their bluetooth sample? https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver

Comment: I haven't embarrassingly, however having quickly read it I seem to be doing everything they are. I'll try fully implementing their sample now though to double check I haven't missed anything. Thank you for the response

Comment: Also try using the Nearby API and connecting your phone to the device, if you can connect to it then you just missed something in your implementation

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Bluetooth is disabled by default on the system image. You need to call enable and then that setting is persistent